# Multiple Versions of jQuery, linking with google no help and neither is noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to have a jquery countdown, carousal and responsive menu on my site, but can't get all of them to work together.. I have tried using the google libraries but then one, two or all of the scripts stop working all together.

Here is the code without the noconflict as it was not working...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/Resp_Menu_Files/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/Resp_Menu_Files/js/orion-menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
            jQuery().orion({
                speed: 500
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you *really* need to use a carousel plugin that requires an ancient version of jQuery? The Internet is full of better ones that would solve your problem immediately.

Comment: ↑↑↑ Otherwise, what's wrong with noConflict()? Check the DOC. But ya, you'd have better to use only newer jq version and use more recent carousel plugin. But as a simple fix, you can pass explicitely jQuery to ready handler for the carousel: `jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {...});`

Comment: Any errors displayed in your console ?

Comment: If i try and use a newer version the carousal doesnt work altogether

Comment: No, I mean *use a different carousel* altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jq142 = jQuery.noConflict(true);


</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/Resp_Menu_Files/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/Resp_Menu_Files/js/orion-menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jq142('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
jQuery().orion({
                speed: 500
            });
});


</script>
```

Comment: I will try that, have already tried the noConflict before but didnt work. might have been used wrong/ :(

Comment: the noConflict did not work. I am thinking i will replace the carousal to solve it.